# Find list of events on calendar occurring within One Day using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, calendar

I wish to find the Count of Events happening on a particular day using C# and Linq. If any events has time on a particular day, then that meeting is included in the day's tally.

Here is my model

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a data set

```
    public static List<Meeting> MockMeetings()
    {
        Meeting m1 = new Meeting { ID = 1, Name = "Meeting 7/21 2pm-3pm 7/21", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 21, 14, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 21, 15, 0, 0) };
        Meeting m2 = new Meeting { ID = 2, Name = "Meeting 7/22 2pm-3pm ", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 22, 14, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 22, 15, 0, 0) };            
        Meeting m3 = new Meeting { ID = 3, Name = "Meeting 7/22 2pm until 7/23 1am", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 22, 14, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 23, 1, 0, 0) };
        Meeting m4 = new Meeting { ID = 4, Name = "Meeting 7/23 1am-2am", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 23, 1, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 23, 2, 0, 0) };
        Meeting m5 = new Meeting { ID = 5, Name = "Meeting 7/22 1am until 7/25 1am", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 22, 1, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 25, 1, 0, 0) };
        Meeting m6 = new Meeting { ID = 6, Name = "Meeting 7/24 11pm-almost midnight", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 24, 23, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 24, 23, 59, 59) };
        Meeting m7 = new Meeting { ID = 7, Name = "Meeting 7/21 1am-2am", Start = new DateTime(2020, 7, 21, 1, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2020, 7, 21, 2, 0, 0) };
        List<Meeting> meetings = new List<Meeting>();
        meetings.Add(m1); meetings.Add(m2); meetings.Add(m3); meetings.Add(m4); meetings.Add(m5); meetings.Add(m6); meetings.Add(m7);
        return meetings;
    }
```

In my code I am cycling through each **day** where the **day value** is new DateTime(2020, 7, 21, 0, 0, 0) etc.  I am having a hard time figuring out meetings spannig multiple days.  I am trying to do this with Linq to SQL.

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
    {
        for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
            yield return day;
    }



    DateTime from = new DateTime(2020, 7, 21);
    DateTime to = new DateTime(2020, 7, 25);

        foreach (DateTime day in Utility.EachDay(from, to))
        {
            List<Meeting> startOK = meetings.Where(p => p.Start >= day).Where(p => p.Start <= day.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1)).ToList();            
            List<Meeting> endOK = startOK.Where(p => p.End >= day).ToList();
            List<Meeting> bothOK = startOK.Union(endOK).DistinctBy(p=>p.ID).ToList();
        }
```

The results I wish to achieve with bothOK are wrong for spanned meetings. This should be the correct answer:

7/21  Meetings 1, 7

7/22  Meetings 2,3,5

7/23  Meetings 3,4,5

7/24  Meetings 5,6

7/25  Meetings 5

Comment: Where is the code, which you've tried to achieve the result? Btw, `List<T>` has a collection initilializer, there is no need to write this `meetings.Add(m1); meetings.Add(m2); meetings.Add(m3); meetings.Add(m4); meetings.Add(m5); meetings.Add(m6); meetings.Add(m7); `

Comment: `endOK.Union(endOK)` do you mean `startOK.Union(endOK)`? will be good to share ``EachDay`` method and `from`,`to` values

Comment: Sajid, thank you  fixed.

Comment: Pavel, my attempt to solve is in the Union statement shown.  Sorry about not using List<T> the way you do. - Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each day, you need to determine if the meeting starts during that day, ends during that day, or completely overlaps that day, so there are three possibilities. Note that your test for `endOK` only includes meetings that start on the day, which excludes overlaps beginning on a previous day.

```
    var startOK = meetings.Where(p => day <= p.Start && p.Start < day.AddDays(1)).ToList();
    var endOK = meetings.Where(p => day <= p.End && p.End <= day.AddDays(1)).ToList();
    var overlapOK = meetings.Where(p => p.Start <= day && day <= p.End).ToList();

    var allOK = startOK.Concat(endOK).Concat(overlapOK).DistinctBy(p => p.ID).ToList();
```